# date picker in django admin

Tags: datepicker, django-admin-filters

I've a model ,response , which is filtered using a date field value in select boxes .  But the filtering options are providing  ranges of date . how can I filter the responses using specific date ?

Answer (score 0):

I Answered that here:

[Filtering by custom date range in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668220/filtering-by-custom-date-range-in-django-admin/10590443#10590443)

You can user the [django-admin-filtrate](https://github.com/runekaagaard/django-admin-filtrate). If you are using django 1.4, put the patch I sent in issues comments.