# Django filter between two time fields

Tags: django, datetime, filter, django-admin

I have such problem. I want to make range filter between start_time and end_time in admin side. So I want to make my own filter which will take this to fields and then filter between them. How do this?

class MyModel(models.Model):

```
start_time = models.DateTimeField()
end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Something like this, but in range of start_time and end_time

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering by custom date range in Django admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668220/filtering-by-custom-date-range-in-django-admin)

Comment: @solarissmoke I think no because he filters only one field, I want to filter in the range of field start_time and end_time. So it will be like this ?start_time__gte=2009-5-1&end_time__lte=2009-8-1