# How to add custom search_field Django admin

Tags: python, django, filter, admin, addition

I want to create a new search field box with my on filters, and add to the django admin:

admin.py

```
  from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Aluno, Data
from .relatorio import salvarRelatorio



class AdminAluno(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_editable = ['is_active',]
    list_display = ['first_name', 'matricula', 'is_active','cpf', 'cargo', 'date_joined','image_tag'] ##mostra esses campos
    search_fields = ['first_name', 'matricula'] ## campos q pesquise
    exclude = ['password']

class AdminData(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['aluno__first_name','data_entrada', 'hora_entrada', 'hora_saida', 'descricao'] ##mostra esses campos
    search_fields = ['aluno__first_name', 'matricula', 'data_entrada'] ## campos q pesquise
    actions = [salvarRelatorio]


admin.site.register(Aluno, AdminAluno)
admin.site.register(Data, AdminData)
```

I want to create a extra search field to filter with data_entrada__gte and data_entrada__lte.

Comment: For better user experience, you might want to consider using a custom filter instead of search fields. Examples can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668220/filtering-by-custom-date-range-in-django-admin

Comment: @karthikr my question is different