# Using date picker as filter in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How to get date picker in Django Admin Filter?

using simple list_filter will get me text selection: Any date, last 7 days, last months etc. But I want simple datepicker, so i can choose just one date... I found django-admin-daterange but I don't need range - just ONE date..

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following to add a date filter:-

```
pip install django-admin-rangefilter
```

then add this to installed apps

```
'rangefilter',
```

then in admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from rangefilter.filter import DateRangeFilter

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ("id", "full_name", "created_at", "role", "is_verified")
  list_filter = (('created_at', DateRangeFilter),  "role")

  admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

this will create a from and to date picker in filter box. you can select one date two files. it will filter a single date.
I referred this blog while solving this problem:-https://www.dothedev.com/blog/2020/04/05/django-admin-list_filter/

Answer (score 0):

> ... but I don't need range - just ONE date..

If you need just one date, you could use `ModelAdmin.date_hierarchy`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.date_hierarchy):

> Set `date_hierarchy` to the name of a `DateField` or `DateTimeField` in your model, and the change list page will include a date-based drilldown navigation by that field.

For example:

```py
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'my_date_field'
```

The result would look like this:

[image: admin date drilldown menu]

This allows you to "drill down" to a single date by selecting *year* -> *month* -> *day*.

It's not an actual calendar-style "date picker" like [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), but I think it's pretty convenient.

For those that *do* need to filter by a *range* of dates, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1670245).