# Django Admin List Filter Specific Date

Tags: django, filter, admin

Is there a way to implement an admin list filter that allows me to pick a specific date for a field on a model?

For instance, I have an Order model with a `order_date` field and I wanna offer a filter that allows the user to put in a specific date such as "06-24-2012" on the admin backend and return a queryset with all the orders having an "order_date" of "06-24-2012".

I know how to implement custom filters via SimpleListFilter, but it doesn't appear that I could use a custom form field in lieu of pre-named filter options like `today` and `tomorrow`.

Is this only achievable via custom html templates?

Comment: You could try https://github.com/runekaagaard/django-admin-filtrate. I had used this for django 1.3.

Comment: You should checkout ModelAdmin queryset , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652305/is-there-a-way-to-filter-a-queryset-in-the-django-admin