# Customizing the feincms page admin based on user

Tags: python, django, django-admin, feincms

I'm trying to find a way to filter the admin queryset for page objects based up on the user provided, what I've considered (pseudo code):

```
from feincms... Page

class MyPageAdmin(PageAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        'monkey business'
        super(MyPageAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

admin.site.unregister(Page)
admin.site.register(Page, MyPageAdmin)
```

This won't work because feincms checks for a completely loaded django instance. A verbose solution would probably be not to load the page module at all, and either override the page model object or admin, e.g.:

```
from feincms... PageAdmin

class MyPage(Page):
    objects = CustomManager()

admin.site.register(MyPage, PageAdmin)
```

The documentation states it is possible to [setup your own page module](http://pythonhosted.org/FeinCMS/admin.html) in a similar way, but it seems a lot of configuration for a simple requirement.

Is there any easier way to override the admin queryset or model admin for feincms modules?

Comment: Shouldn't overriding the [queryset method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1659129/630877) of the standard `PageAdmin` work?

Comment: @arie, yes but not in the conventional way, I just figured out how to patch them correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FeinCMS v1.7 also allows you to set `FEINCMS_USE_PAGE_ADMIN=False` in your Django settings.

Then, just subclass `PageAdmin` as you normally would, and register the model admin with the model yourself.

You should also start importing `PageAdmin` from `feincms.module.page.modeladmins` if you're using v1.7.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is you cannot unregister the feincms modules because of some magic performed. Instead of registering your own feincms Page object, you can patch the methods like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from feincms.module.page.models import PageAdmin

def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(PageAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(site__id__exact=settings.SITE_ID)
PageAdmin.queryset = queryset
```