# How to reuse existing admin models to display a custom Queryset?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I'm writing my first application in Django, and now that the base is covered, I try to enhance a bit the admin part to ease up my life.

I have two classes in my model:

```
class Puzzle(models.Model):
    puzzle_pieces = models.ForeignKey(PuzzlePieces,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PuzzlePieces(models.Model):
    puzzle_pieces = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='empty')
```

with admin models in place too:

```
class PuzzlePiecesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

class PuzzleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
```

I want to define in the PuzzlePiecesAdmin class a custom action to display (reusing the format defined in PuzzleAdmin) all the puzzles which are linked to the selected puzzle_pieces

I know how to create custom actions,

```
def show_related_puzzles(modeladmin, request, queryset):
```

I've seen on the internet different ways to filter directly within the PuzzleAdmin class,
but not how to set the queryset from the outside.

But I don't understand how to launch the display of an instance of  PuzzleAdmin limited to the queryset I will define within show_related_puzzles.

Could anyone explain me how to proceed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the start of an answer in the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1652377/12505071

> the standard changelist view accepts normal queryset filter parameters as GET arguments. So you can do:
>
> `/admin/puzzles/puzzle/?puzzle_pieces__pk=21`

I finally found out by trial and error how to add another filter:

```
/admin/puzzles/puzzle/?difficulty__id__exact=35&puzzle__pk=560
```

Could anybody tell me how to add a second value for the same parameter?

Comment: OK, I found the solution: we use the "__in" filter:

Comment: /admin/puzzles/puzzle/?puzzle_pieces__pk__in=21,22